# Evaluate $3\times(9^{(\frac12)})\times(27^{(\frac14)})*(81^{(\frac18)}\cdots\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, exponentiation

Here expression can be written as 
$$3\times(3^{(\frac22)})\times(3^{(\frac34)})\times(3^{(\frac48)})....
= 3^{(1+1+(\frac34)+(\frac48)+(\frac5{16})\cdots\infty)}$$

What will be the next step after this?

Answer (score 1):

So your sum is

$$
 3^{\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)/2^k}
$$

The exponent can be evaluated:
$$
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)/2^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 1/2^k + \sum_{k=0}^\infty k/2^k = 2 + 2 = 4
$$

So your sum is $3^4 = 81$.

EDIT by request:
The last sum can be evaluated as follows:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{-k} = -\sum_{k=0}^\infty k/x^{k+1} = - \frac1x \sum_{k=0}^\infty k/x^{k} 
$$
but also
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{-k} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{1}{1-1/x} = -1/(x - 1)^2
$$
Equating the two results gives 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty k/x^{k}  = x/(x - 1)^2
$$
For $x=2$ we obtain
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty k/2^{k}  = 2
$$

Comment: how is (0 to infinity)sum (k/(2^k)) =2?

Comment: I put it in the  text.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to find the exponent
Let S
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(\frac{k+1}{2^k})=(1+\frac22+\frac34+...)$$
$$2S=2+(1+\frac32+\frac44+...)$$
Subtracting gives
$$S=2+(1+\frac32+\frac44+...)-(1+\frac22+\frac34+...)$$
Note that we can rearrange as the series converges
$$S=2+(1+\frac12+\frac14+...)$$
The terms in bracket is a Geometric infinite series
$$S=2+(\frac{1}{1-\frac12})$$
$$S=4$$
So
$$3^{\sum_{k=0}^\infty(\frac{k+1}{2^k})}=3^{4}=81$$

Comment: You're welcome...